# including npm module in google cloud functions

Tags: javascript, npm, google-cloud-functions

I am trying to include local npm package in a cloud function. I used the following commands:

```bsh
$ npm pack
$ npm install --save tarball-output.tgz
```

How do I include a packed npm package in app.js? I used:

```js
let mypackage = require('my_package');
```

I getting the following error when trying to deploy:

```bsh
ERROR: (gcloud.beta.functions.deploy) OperationError: code=3,
message=Function load error: Code in file app.js can't be loaded. 
Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies? 
Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'my_package'
```

Answer (score 0):

Your package.json must point to your tarball, like this:

```
{
  "dependencies": {
    "my_package": "file:tarball-output.tgz"
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes I did. Finally I found the issue. It was because the name of the local package included capita letters. Now it is working or me.